# Insert PHP into wordpress page

Tags: php

I want to use the following code in my wordpress page. How can I do that?

```
<?php
$theme_name = get_template();
$directory = "wp-content/themes/" . $theme_name . "/pdf/ECE340/";
$pdfs= glob($directory . "*.pdf");
foreach($pdfs as $pdf)
{
$link= substr($pdf,48,90);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $pdf;?> "><?php echo $link;?></a>
<?php
echo "\n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: You should probably read the [Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) page on the Codex. It describes what a WordPress page is and what you can do with it. Including using a template file to add PHP code to it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a DUPLICATE!**

You will find the same question answered by me [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117456/insert-php-in-wordpress-page/117476).